# Serenity Cucumber - Make sure element is within the viewport

Tags: selenium, cucumber, serenity-bdd

In Serenity Cucumber, some methods do not scroll the element into the view port: for example, the getValue() method will just get that value and not scroll the browser so that the element is in view, which causes the report to just show a screen shot of the top of the page, but not the element that is being interacted with.

Example current method:

```
@Step("read first name")
public String readFirstName() {
  return $(ContactPage.firstNameField).getValue();
}
```

Example of my attempt(s) to scroll the element into view, so it shows on the screenshot:

```
@Step("read first name")
public String readFirstName() {
  new ScrollToBy(ContactPage.firstNameField).andAlignToTop();
  return $(ContactPage.firstNameField).getValue();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use something like screenplay pattern questions/tasks for [reading off-screen text](https://serenity-bdd.github.io/theserenitybook/latest/screenplay-selenium-tasks.html#_reading_off_screen_text).

```java
@Subject("the displayed text")
public class TextValue implements Question<String> {

    private Target target

    @Override
    public String answeredBy(Actor actor) {
        return target.resolveFor(actor).getText();
    }

    private TextValue(Target target) {
        this.target = target;
    }

    public static Question<String> of(Target target) { return new TextValue(target); }
}
```

Then in your steps...

```java
theActorInTheSpotlight().wasAbleTo(Scroll.to(ContactPage.firstNameField));
theActorInTheSpotlight().should(eventually(
    seeThat(the(TextValue.of(ContactPage.firstNameField)), 
            isEqualTo(expectedValue))
));
```

Comment: I don't need to get the text of it, I need it to show up in the screen shot

Comment: The point was to show how you can compose multple steps so it does show up in the screen shot. All my test steps are showing screens as expected.

Comment: To be more clear, the first statement will scroll to the target in question, while the second statement waits for it to come into view before reading the text value. You can do this anywhere you have a valid reference to the `Actor`.